# How do I return a value from a function that modifies a global variable?

Tags: sh

If I want to store the output from a function *f* I can do `result=$(f)` but this will not work if *f* modifies a global variable since f is executed in a subshell.

Here is an example which illustrates the problem:

```
x=0

f()
{
    x=1
    echo "f"
}

result=$(f)
```

At the end *result* is "f" but *x* is (still) 0. Is there a way to call *f* so that it has a side effect *and* to store the result in a variable?

Comment: set a second variable

Comment: can you elaborate on the case and what won't work ?

Comment: @LiMar OK, I have added an example.

Comment: Yes, the code is correct so ... What do you want to achieve ?? Try to explain everything and you'll start to receive answers.

Comment: do you really mean `sh`? not `bash, ksh, zsh, etc`? Good luck.

Comment: @LiMar I basically want to store the result of a function in a variable and I want the function to affect the global state.

Comment: @shellter Yes, I prefer to be POSIX compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

**1) Call the function NOT in a subshell and use `return` with some return code**

```
f()
{
   x=1
   return 15
}

x=0
f
r=$?
echo "$r $x"
```

Will result in:

```
15 1
```

Thus you both changed `x` *and* got some return code (even not a string)

**2) IPC between shell and subshell**

Subshell is another process so it can't get to the variables of then parent shell.

But you can build some custom messaging. 
The simplest - store you "side effects" in a file which is perfect global variable storage.

```
f()
{
    echo "1" > x.tmp
    echo "f"
}

result=$(f) #"x" value is stored in x.tmp
```

**3)Return both the result and the side effect together as concatenated result.**

```
f() 
{
     x=1
     echo "$x:f" 
}

result_with_separator=$(f)
```

Comment: Strategy number two seems to fit, never thought of it. Thanks for the detailed answer LiMar.